# PhoneGap 3.1 Build Device Is Not Defined

Tags: android, ios, extjs, cordova

I have a sencha touch project. I was build with phonegap 2.9 and works fine device.uuid returning to device Id. When I tried the build with 3.1 device.uuid throwing " Device Is Not Defined" error.
My config.xml

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.1.0" />
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true" />
<access origin="*" />

<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" />
<gap:splash src="images/splash.png" />

<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera" />

<feature name="Device">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
</feature>
```

My Device ID request:

```
 try
{
   Ext.getCmp('txtUUID').setValue(device.uuid);
}
catch(err)
{alert(err);

    Ext.getCmp('txtUUID').setValue('ID Okunamadı!');

}
```

I need help. How to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are building with phonegap build, right?

In phonegap 3, the core api are no more included by default and are now plugins, so you have to explicitly add any api you are using.

You should be able to read the UUID after adding the following line to config.xml :

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
```

And you can also remove the following lines since the API features are now handled by the new plugin format.

useless lines:

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera" />
<feature name="Device">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
</feature>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer QuickFix, i tried your answer but still now working.

<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.0.0" />
 <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true" />
 <access origin="*" />
 
 <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
 <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" />

Comment: I haven't developed in sencha yet, but I had a similar issue in jQuery Mobile and I solved it using deferred objects to check when device is ready and execute the phonegap code until the device is ready, check if it works for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/22570149/2532797

Answer (score 1):

Put your registration code under DeviceReady function

```
var platform = null;
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
          platform = device.platform;
          //alert(platform);
          $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>'+ platform +'</li>');
          try 
            { 
                pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
          $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>registering ' + device.platform + '</li>');
                if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' ||
                        device.platform == 'amazon-fireos' ) {
        pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {"senderID":"860557673192","ecb":"onNotification"});        // required!
                } else {
                    pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"onNotificationAPN"});    // required!
                }
            }
            catch(err) 
            { 
                txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n"; 
                txt+="Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n"; 
                alert(txt); 
            } 
        }
```